# How to access the data attribute value using data set

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/Su97P/2/
```

I dont know whats wrong with this code. I would like to click on the green div and by that click add "data-productName" to the "cart".

```
   var cart = []; 
var cartElement = document.getElementById("cart");



function addToCart(productName) {
   cart.push(productName); 
   cartElement.innerHTML = cart.join("<br>");  
}


var someDiv = document.getElementById("product");

someDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var str = someDiv.dataset.productName; 

   addToCart(str); 

}, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to `productname`, since the data attributes are lowercased in your case (camelcased in case of any more hyphens after the first one) and added to the dataset, you need to access it as `productname` instead of `productName`.

```
someDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var str = someDiv.dataset.productname; 
   addToCart(str); 
}, false);
```

`productName` will work had your attribute been `data-product-name`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) regarding the rules.

- any dash (U+002D) is removed;
- any letter following a dash (U+002D), before its removal, is set in its uppercase counterpart.

Comment: Im sorry, change which part to productname?

Comment: @user2915962 see the casing... when you do `someDiv.dataset.productname`

Comment: Sure! How do I do that?

Comment: I think i found it, took care of some old ones to =)

Comment: @user2915962 That's good, in fact that will help any future visitors as well to find out more appropriate answer in most cases :)

Comment: Can I Ask you something else? In the example in the fiddle there is just one "product" (the green div), how do I do if I have many different elements to add?

Comment: @user2915962 you can without duplicating the ids. provide them all a classname as product and use document.getElementsByClassName('product'), loop though them attach the handler and then inthe handler use `this.dataset.productname`

Comment: Thank you again, im new at this as you may notice, please have a look at this fiddle where I tried to do what you said:
http://jsfiddle.net/bald1/Su97P/10/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41284/discussion-between-psl-and-user2915962)